# Repl.it problem during pip installation (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, replit

I have just created a repl.it Python project, and my `pyproject.toml` is as follows:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "python-template"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
numpy = "^1.22.2"
replit = "^3.2.4"
Flask = "^2.2.0"
discord = "^2.0"
python-dotenv = "^0.19.0"
dnspython = "^1.16.0"
PyNaCl = "^1.3.0"
async-timeout = "^3.0.1"
requests = "^2.28.0"
discord-webhook = "^0.16.3"
psutil = "^5.9.1"
pytz = "^2022.1"
futures = "<3.0.0"
PyDictionary = "2.0.1"
youtube-dl = "2021.2.10"
speedtest-cli = "^2.1.3"
roblox = "^2.0.0"
aiohttp = "^3.7.4"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
debugpy = "^1.6.2"
python-lsp-server = {extras = ["yapf", "rope", "pyflakes"], version = "^1.5.0"}
toml = "^0.10.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I am running on Python 3.9.6.

Whenever I try to use `pip install <package>`, I always get the following error:

```
An error occurred during configuration: option use-feature: invalid choice: 'content-addressable-pool' (choose from '2020-resolver', 'fast-deps', 'in-tree-build')
```

When I run the project on my own computer, I do not get any errors. I also could not find any instances of this error online.

I have no idea what went wrong - it seems like a normal Python installation to me. Can someone please point out what is the problem with this?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: @blockhead Indeed I did. Under `.config/pip/pip.conf`, there was the invalid option `content-addressable-pool` which I removed. This is an error on replit's side, included in every default Python environment, and I have contacted them about it